# Pass data from parent to child window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am very new to front-end development and I am trying to pass some data from my parent window to my child window but it just comes up as [object][object]

**js**

```
 $scope.openLargeGraph = function() {
   var childWindow = window.open('graphs.html', "", "width=950,height=850");
   var testData = $scope.data;
   childWindow.data = testData;

   childWindow.document.write(childWindow.data);
   console.log(testData)

   console.log(childWindow.data);

   // childWindowForGraph.moveTo(300, 50);
 };
```

Comment: Opening child windows in single-page apps (SPA) is unusual at best.  Consider using a modal like the ui bootstrap modal that can be found here (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) as it is consistent with the mvc patterns of AngularJS.

Comment: you can put the data in `localStorage` then on child load read it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the data in `window.localStorage` before you open the window. then read it back on load of the new window.

See online demo - **https://plnkr.co/edit/nEjjzLC4pVvg1nOsXlgA?p=preview**

---

**index.html**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    layout: 'spring',
    nodes: [{name:'Node 1', x: 2, y: 4 },{name:'Node 2', x: 2, y: 4 }] 
  };

  $scope.openLargeGraph = function() {
    // Save data on local storage
    window.localStorage['graph:data'] = angular.toJson($scope.data);
    window.open('graphs.html', "", "width=950,height=850");
  };

});
```

**graphs.html**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage['graph:data']);
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/nEjjzLC4pVvg1nOsXlgA?p=preview

---

Do note that it's not considered best practice, if possible use the same page and change views asynchronously (google *angular SPA application*)

I'm guessing you want to isolate some part of your app that renders a graph to a different window, hopes this help you with what you want

Comment: what would happen if both html pages shared the same controller.... What I am trying to accomplish is opening a child window with larger graphs in them... in order to do this, I have a chart library(that is a directive), and supporting data that needs to be passed over

Comment: The technique above will work even if you use the same controller. load on start, save before open

Answer (score 0):

if u access like that it will show u as object format only,try like this in your console

```
 console.log(childWindow.data[0]);
 console.log(childWindow.data[1]);
```

then u can see graphs.html for first console and width=950,height=850 for second

Comment: undefined... I dont think my var is being passed to the child window

Comment: console.log($scope.data); run this and post the data u get from this

Answer (score 0):

you could use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to transfer data between windows:

```
$scope.openLargeGraph = function () {
    var childWindow = window.open('graphs.html', "", "width=950,height=850");
    if(childWindow) //in case the new window blocked by browser
        childWindow.postMessage($scope.data, '*');
};
```

Then in graphs.html, add message event listener:

```
//graphs.html
window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    document.write(event.data);
}, false);
```

Comment: seems like race condition  (posting before listening, since you cant rely on the child window loading time)

Comment: Yeah, I dont see it coming through